# Is there an online sample movie to test MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, streaming-video

I have the iPhone successfully trying to open a movie online. (It fails because I don't have a real URL.)

Does anyone know of a working URL I could use as a baseline test to make sure my code is working? I know the iPhone is a bit picky about formats and MIME types and the server, so I want to start with a known working stream.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

try [this URL](http://s3.amazonaws.com/videos.belacena.iol.pt/2009_6_www.belacena.com_15746_novo_apple_iphone_3g_s.mp4).

It streams fine on my iPhone app using MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: You just saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: I have tried to use this URL in a project running on iPad and it says "this video cannot be played"... very strange

Answer (score 11):

Got error note saying that the video doesn't exist any more. Here's another one, from Apple Knowledge Base document. Maybe it stays around longer:

> http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1211 Verifying iTunes video conversion and video syncing using sample QuickTime files
>
> http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1211/sample_iTunes.mov

...but you really can't trust on hardcoded video URLs to remain alive for years. What you should do is a **search google** like:

> sample filetype:mov

Answer (score -4):

here is another ,hope it will be help full

link http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp